# Rendering bits from multiple GoPro 7 footage into one file to save space and time without loosing quality

Tags: premiere, gopro

I would like to render bits from multiple GoPro 7 (4k 60fps) footage into one file to save space and time in future (browsing).

So instead of keeping 100 footage files, there would be just one file with compilation of usable clips.

I would like to do this without loosing quality or frame rate.

What are the best settings in Premiere to save the closest possible output to the original?

I understand the resolution and frame rate needs to be set up to match the footage, but what about other settings which could possibly make Premiere manipulate the frames as little as possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for are lossless codecs. Export with the exact same settings that your footage was recorded in, but use a codec such as Prores4444xq or DNxHD, with no subsampling and 16 bit video-depth.